# Decoding Python 3.7.4 Filenames That Were Created With VB

Tags: python

I have some files in a Windows 10 directory that were named with encryption logic written in VB.  The VB logic was originally written on Windows 7 with VB.net, but the file names are exactly the same between the two version of Windows, as expected.  The problem I'm having is that when I try to decrypt those file names in a character by character loop in Python 3.7.4, what is returned from the ord() function doesn't match what the VB asc() designation is for that character.

All the letters match (up to ascii character 126) but everything after that does not.

For example, in VB:

```
?asc("ƒ")
```

returns 131.

However, in Python 3.4.7:

```
ord('ƒ')
```

returns 402.

I've read a lot of great posts here discussing UTF-8 vs cp1252 encoding both for strings of data (within files) and filenames, but I haven't come across a solution for my problem.

When I run:

```
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

I get 'utf-8'.  This is what, I believe, would be used for file names, and functions used for them, e.g., os.fsdecode(), os.listdir(), etc..

When I run:

```
locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

I get 'cp1252.'

One thing I noticed on the "other side of the fence," is that the values returned by python ord () DO match the VB equivalent AscW(), but altering all that code is going to be more problematic than moving forward with the rest of what we've done in Python so far.

Should I be altering the locale's preferredencoding or the sys's default encoding to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Python value is the [Unicode code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%91#Appearance_in_computer_fonts) (and is bigger than 255).  If you already have the correct filenames in Python, just encode the strings with the appropriate encoding (apparently `cp1252`) and examine the byte values.  (You could also call functions like `os.listdir` with `bytes` arguments to suppress the decoding in the first place.)